# How to mock UIApplication in Swift?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, bdd

I'm currently using Quick + Nimble for my unit testing in Swift. I'm building an `Inviter` class that sends app invites via different methods.

I need to mock out UIApplication to verify that my code calls `openURL`.

My code so far:

```
import Quick
import Nimble
import OCMock

extension Inviter {
    convenience init(usingMockApplication mockApplication: UIApplication) {
        self.init()
        application = mockApplication
    }
}

class MockUIApplication : UIApplication {
    var application = UIApplication.sharedApplication()

    var openedURL: String?

    override func openURL(url: NSURL) -> Bool {
        openedURL = url.absoluteString
        return true
    }
}

class InviterSpec: QuickSpec {
    override func spec() {

        describe("Inviter") {
            var mockApplication = MockUIApplication()
            var inviter = Inviter(usingMockApplication: mockApplication)

            beforeEach() {
                inviter = Inviter(usingMockApplication: mockApplication)
            }

            context("for WhatsApp invites") {
                beforeEach() {
                    inviter.inviteViaWhatsAppWithMessage("Invite Message.")
                }

                it("should tell the application to open WhatsApp") {
                    expect(mockApplication.openedURL).toNot(beNil())
                }

                it("should send WhatsApp the right message") {
                    let message = mockApplication.openedURL?.lastPathComponent
                    expect(message).to(equal("Invite%Message."))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this approach, my app errors at runtime stating there can understandably be only one `UIApplication`. Previously, one could make `MockUIApplication` inherit from `NSObject`, and pass that in. Unfortunately Swift's strict type checking seems to prevent that too.

Would love any ideas.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I've got the same problem right now.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are close. Use a protocol for the functions you need.

```
protocol UIApplicationProtocol {
    func openURL(url: NSURL) -> Bool
}

extension UIApplication: UIApplicationProtocol {}
```

Then you just need to use the protocol instead of the class

```
extension Inviter {
    convenience init(usingMockApplication mockApplication: UIApplicationProtocol) {
        self.init()
        application = mockApplication
    }
}
```

You will need to modify the `Inviter` class to use `UIApplicationProtocol` as well.