# Mock UIApplication open function in iOS 10

Tags: swift, mocking, ios10, uiapplication

I previously mocked the `UIApplication` in my app this way: [How to mock UIApplication in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244157/how-to-mock-uiapplication-in-swift)

We now want to get iOS 10 devices to use `open(_ url: URL, options: [String : Any] = [:], completionHandler completion: ((Bool) -> Swift.Void)? = nil)` function as `openURL(_ url: URL) -> Bool` is deprecated. I don't seem to be able to mock this in the same way though.

**Current Code**

```
protocol BSApplicationProtocol {
    func openURL(url: URL) -> Bool

    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func open(_ url: URL, options: [String : Any], completionHandler completion: ((Bool) -> Swift.Void)?)
}

extension UIApplication: BSApplicationProtocol {
    internal func openURL(url: URL) -> Bool {
        return openURL(url)
    }

    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    internal func open(_ url: URL, options: [String : Any], completionHandler completion: ((Bool) -> Swift.Void)?) {
        open(url, options: options, completionHandler: completion)
    }
}

func openAppSettings(application: BSApplicationProtocol = UIApplication.shared) {

    if let settingsURL = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {        
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            application.open(settingsURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
             _ = application.openURL(url: settingsURL)
        }
    }
}
```

When running on an iOS 10 device, the `open(_ url: URL, options: [String : Any] = [:], completionHandler completion: ((Bool) -> Swift.Void)? = nil)` function is called but it ends up crashing in the `UIApplication` extension class with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

In the screenshot attached below, you can see the old open function is in blue but the new one is green. This makes me think I am somehow referencing the function incorrectly.

[image]

Are there any tips on where I may be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to give the function (in the `BSApplicationProtocol`) a different name.

`open()` --> `open2()` for example. (NOTE: You should probably come up with a better function name than this though)

Obviously then you have to change the function name in the `extension` and the function named called from within my `openAppSettings` function.

I'm not exactly sure why I didn't have to name `openURL` something different. The only difference I see between these two is that `OpenURL` returns a `Bool` and the new iOS 10 version has default values.